# Magento 1.9 - How to write script for bulk update values in table using csv?

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, category-products, table, bulk-products-update

Try to bulk update label name in **catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value**,

CSV formate :

[image]

Workout:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask("0");
Mage::app();

ini_set('display_errors',"1");
ini_set('display_startup_errors', "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

    if (($handle = fopen("inputs.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, '1000', ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            $sql='UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value SET label='.$data['2'].' WHERE value_id = '.$data['0'].'';
            echo $sql.'<br/>';
            mysqli_query($sql); 


        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
?>
```

How to alter my script for Magento 1.9?

Comment: May I know in csv where product id defined?check these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948063/magento-import-product-images-media-via-csv

Comment: @Jinesh The above link you shown for default import from magento, i asking about directly update with sql table. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTtk0.png

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask("0");
Mage::app();

ini_set('display_errors',"1");
ini_set('display_startup_errors', "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$connection=Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    if (($handle = fopen("inputs.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, '1000', ",")) !== FALSE)
        {


            $sql = "UPDATE " . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value') . " cped
                SET  cped.label = ?
            WHERE  cped.value_id = ?";
            $connection->query($sql, array($data['2'], $data['0']));


        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank You, In Magento 2.3 instead of this -> Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName(' ')  what i should be replace?

Comment: are you developer?

Comment: Please accept my answer for this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56829263/update-product-attribute-via-mysql-in-magento-1-9/56831636?noredirect=1#comment107271049_56831636

Comment: Yes, learning Magento 2.3

Comment: I am looking job change if you have some work let me know.

Comment: Try following way to get table name in magento2 :- 

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('employee');

Comment: okay, sure. For my simple suggestion keep updating your profile in Naukri, LinkedIn and Neuvoo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105433/discussion-between-jinesh-and-zus).